# Using one cell's value in a formula to look up a particular cell

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I cannot work this problem out in Google Sheets.

I have a cell where I enter a number. 
This number should be used to tell other cells exactly what cell they should be looking at as part of a formula.

For example

Cell B2 is a user input cell and the user enters “3”.

In cell B3 I need this formula but in a way that works =’another sheet’!A(B2)  where (B2) should be the value from the cell B2.

So effectively in this case the cell B3 would show the data from =’another sheet’!A3
Or if the cell B2 had 57 entered, B3 would show the data from =’another sheet’!A57

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indirect` to provide the functionality, along with `&`.

```
=indirect("Sheet1!"&"A"&B2)
```

If cell B2 has a value of `5`, this will be equivalent to `Sheet1!A5`.

Answer (score 1):

```
=index('another sheet'!A:A, B2, 1)
```

`indirect()`, like the other answer suggested, will also work but, in general, solutions with `indirect` should always be the last resort; they are harder to debug and more prone to breaking, for example if you change the sheet name.